# Azure Management group does not have any valid subscriptions

Tags: azure, cost-management, azure-management-groups

In an attempt to view the cost analysis at the Management group level, I am receiving the following error message:

> Management group LandingZone does not have any valid subscriptions. (Request ID: 3867f325-14c1-4181-bc25-0299516c0b25)

[image]

It has the following subscriptions

[image]

Comment: Can you make sure that the subscriptions under selected management group are Supportedr? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cost-management-billing/costs/understand-cost-mgt-data#supported-microsoft-azure-offers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably you have 2 directories: directory `A` and directory `B`.

You can check that if you go into your account and you have `Switch Directory`:

[image]

The billing of all the subscriptions in directory `A` are redirected into directory `B` or the other way around.

**EDIT:** In this case what you need to do is to go to Cost Management, create a view with all the subscription that are in the directory A and a view with all the subscriptions in the directory B and save.
Use that to see the totals

Comment: Let's say, thses subscriptions are part of the management group in directory-A but billing is associated with directory-B. In this case, don't I see the cost analysis for the management group is in directory-A? If so, how do I setup the budget combining all these subscriptions?How do I check the subscription to find the associated directory and its billing details?

Comment: Before I say something wrong, can you check if you have "switch directory"? That will be the proof. I will later tell you what to do.

Comment: Yes, I see - switch directory

Comment: Make a list of the subscriptions and include only those in your metrics

Answer (score 0):

If your subscription is managed by a CSP then the problem is this:

> Management groups in CSP scopes aren't supported by Cost Management.
> If you have a CSP subscription and you set the scope to a management
> group in cost analysis, an error similar the following one is shown:
>
> *Management group  does not have any valid subscriptions*

See [Understand and work with scopes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cost-management-billing/costs/understand-work-scopes#cloud-solution-provider-csp-scopes)